# Android Java to C# URL

Tags: c#, java, android, xamarin.android

What is the C# equivalent of the following Java snippet below:

```
Drawable image;
URL imageUrl;

imageUrl = new URL(getMyImageUrl(imageNumber));
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageUrl.openStream());
image = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more literal conversion to C# would be:

```
var imageUrl = new Java.Net.URL(GetMyImageUrl(imageNumber));
var bitmap   = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeStream (imageUrl.OpenStream ());
var image    = new Android.Graphics.Drawables.BitmapDrawable (bitmap);
```

This is one of the strengths of Mono for Android: the classes and methods mirror the underlying Java platform (with some exceptions) while providing much of the .NET framework, so migrating code from Java to C# should be reasonably straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

```
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Drawing.Imaging;

  public Bitmap DownloadImage(string imageUrl)
  {
        try
        {
              WebClient client = new WebClient();

              using(Stream stream = client.OpenRead(imageUrl))
              {
                    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
              }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
              //todo: handle me
              throw;
        }

        return bitmap
  }
```

Comment: Really?  That's not valid C#.  Would suggest a `using` statement for the Stream, losing the `private` keywords and including the call to `getMyImageUrl` in the question.  Just trying to be helpful

Comment: `Flush` is something you call on write streams, more to the point

Comment: @Kieren oh i see, ill clear it up. i was not trying to provide compile-ready code just general guidelines

Comment: @Kieren: You don't have to do it if you are going to call `Close()` in the next statement. Just saying.

Comment: This solution works perfectly. JonP's solution is directed more towards the Monodroid framework.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2555.htm . I assumed you would want to use Bitmap. I have never used **Drawable** in Java, so correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Drawable is android-specific thing.

Comment: Ok but would Bitmap be the equivalent, or was I that far off?